# Opening a file using absolute path

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to open a file using an absolute path. I'm currently doing this in Windows but will also need this to work in a Unix environement.

The path is composed using an environment variable as shown below.

```
char *dataPath = getenv ("DATA");
strcat(dataPath, "/index");
char indexPath[255] = {0};
strcat(indexPath, dataPath);
strcat(indexPath, "/index.tbl");
printf("Path: %s\n", indexPath);
ip = fopen(indexPath, "r");
```

This code prints out C:\Data/index/index.tbl but the application fails to open the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
char *dataPath = getenv ("DATA");
strcat(dataPath, "/index");
```

and may be overwriting a part of the process' environment block. From [man getenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv):

> As typically implemented, getenv() returns a pointer to a string within the environment list. The caller must take care not to modify this string, since that would change the environment of the process.

You need to allocate a buffer large enough to contain the full path and copy in `getenv("DATA")` and then `strcat()` or `sprintf()`:

```
const char* dataPath = getenv("DATA");
char* fullPath = 0;
if (dataPath)
{
    /* 6 for "/index" and 1 for terminating null character. */
    fullPath = malloc(strlen(dataPath) + 6 + 1);
    if (fullPath)
    {
        sprintf(fullPath, "%s/index", dataPath);

        free(fullPath);
    }
}
```